# Supported hardware list 2021?

Tags: hardware, hardware-certification

I'm having trouble finding an up to date (well, actually finding any working) supported hardware lists. It seems that "Linux Friendly", "Component Catalog", and "Hardware4Linux" are all defunct. Surely there's some way to get an idea about the chances of a device working other than buying it, trying it, and having to send it back if not? Amazon's real forgiving of that, of course, but it takes a lot of time to try each item. What am I missing?

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/certified  anything else is really hit or miss.  It is up to the manufacturer of the hardware to support Linux or not.

Comment: This doesn't appear to include peripherals?

Comment: Pretty good article about Linux compatible hardware which is still pretty true today about it.  https://www.linux.com/news/my-hardware-linux-compatible-find-out-here/

Answer (score 2):

Hardware tested by Canonical is posted at https://ubuntu.com/certified.

It's not an exhaustive list. It includes only hardware that OEMs decided to send for testing.

Comment: Does this include peripherals? I need a wifi dongle...

Comment: WiFi dongles depend entirely upon the chipset inside the dongle. The brand name on the outside means little. Some manufacturers might switch chipsets without making any changes to the packaging. In other words, be prepared to test and return dongles that seems to work fine for somebody else. It's a bit of the Wild West.

Comment: Is there somewhere that lists the supported chipsets? It would be nice to at least know that some variant of a device has a decent chance, rather than simply guess, try, return, repeat :)